# When using registerForActivityResult in a fragment the callback is never called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions

I'm using registerForActivityResult as the StartActivityForResult function is deprecated. So we are migrating toward the new way using registerForActivityResult. This works perfectly in Activities. However when using this in a fragment the callback is never called. I must also mention that the parent activity and other child fragments handles some results in the old way. When I debug the code i see that the onActivityResult or onRequestPermissionsResult of the parent is called but never the callback.
This is the code in the parent activity:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    when (resultCode) {
        Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
            when (requestCode) {
                RC_ONBOARDING_COMPLETE -> {
                    HomeActivity.start(this)
                    finish()
                }
                else -> super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
            }
        }
        else -> super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

The child fragment:

```
val requestPermissionsLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>> =
    registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
    ) { grantMap ->
        accessLocationRequested(!grantMap.containsValue(false) && grantMap.isNotEmpty())
    }
```

and behind a button :

```
requestPermissionsLauncher.launch(
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                )
            )
```

I also use appcompat 1.3.0-rc01 the latest version available.
Any ideas why the parent doesnt forward the result to the child?
Oh yeah i checked this in the activity and i returns true:

```
activityResultRegistry.dispatchResult(
        requestCode, Activity.RESULT_OK, Intent()
            .putExtra(EXTRA_PERMISSIONS, permissions)
            .putExtra(EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANT_RESULTS, grantResults)
    )
```

Comment: Do you override `onRequestPermissionsResult` in your activity? I don't understand your last code block - are you manually calling `dispatchResult()`? You should never be doing that in your app code.

Comment: Hello, no I added those as a check while debugging. Since calling `dispatchResult()` returns true if the call is registered. So that piece of code was only for debugging purposes. I don't call `onRequestPermissionsResult` in my activity. I only added it for debug purposes to see if that callback would be executed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the sollution. It was not related to the library.
In our base implementation of fragments we use:

```
override fun getLifecycle(): LifecycleRegistry
```

This breaks the callback mechanism.